# HTTP Error 500.19 - IIS Error

Tags: iis-7.5, asp.net, windows, web.config, custom-errors

I have following lines in my web.config file. All I am trying to achieve is to display a custom error page if anything goes wrong in application. But instead of getting the custom page I get error as in attached image. Any idea why ? I am running asp.net 4 website on IIS7.5.

[image]

```
</httpErrors>
```

Comment: Have you tried using Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager to modify the web.config file for you? There are instructions at [HTTP Errors <httpErrors>](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors).

Answer (score 1):

According to this [MSDN Blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2010/03/08/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7.aspx), the error code `0x80070021` suggests that "The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file."

You can try unlocking the highlighted section of your file or not use it to solve this error. You should check out the blog entry for further detailed solution.

Alternatively, you may also check [this solution on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12867753).